# Firewall Rule One way smb in two network

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall, mikrotik

Im trying to make an one way smb firewall rule in a MikroTik firewall rule

The thing is I have two network one on 192.168.1.0/24 and one 192.168.3.0/24

192.168.3.0 is the network that should be able to access the smb's on the 192.168.1.0/24 network
But network 192.168.1.0/24 should be able to connect to any smb on it's network.

And beacause there is a Data Server on 192.168.3.5 id like to have both network be able to access it.

Here is my two rule in fire wall

[image][image]

Now the first expected behaviour work ( 192.168.3.0/24 can access all smb's on 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 can't access 192.168.3.0/24 )

But Rule number 2 don't work ( I want to let 192.168.0.1/24 to access only 192.168.3.5 smb)

I Think it because the first rule drop the packet and the packet dont even get filter by the second rule.  So Here I am Is it possible to reproduce the beaviour that im expecting ??

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally realized why this was happening, And I though every one should know that the order of rules in the firewall is important!

See the next picture

[image]

ps:Rule #0 and #2 are identical

If I enable rule 0 and disable rule 2 it does'nt work. But if i have 0 disabled and 2 enabled it work!